# Embedded ActiveMQ for unit test is throwing JMSException when the test ends

Tags: spring-boot, activemq-classic, spring-jms, spring-boot-test

I am using embedded activeMQ for junit test with spring JMS. The tests are all passing. But when the test is finished, following exception is seeing in the logs. How can I solve this error coming in logs

```
javax.jms.JMSException: Disposed due to prior exception
at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:72)
at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.syncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1421)
at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.close(ActiveMQConnection.java:688)
at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.closeConnection(SingleConnectionFactory.java:501)
at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.resetConnection(SingleConnectionFactory.java:389)
at org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.resetConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:205)
at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.onException(SingleConnectionFactory.java:367)
at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory$AggregatedExceptionListener.onException(SingleConnectionFactory.java:721)
at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection$5.run(ActiveMQConnection.java:1967)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)                                                        
Caused by: org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportDisposedIOException: Disposed due to prior exception
at org.apache.activemq.transport.ResponseCorrelator.onException(ResponseCorrelator.java:125)
at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.onException(TransportFilter.java:114)
at org.apache.activemq.transport.vm.VMTransport.stop(VMTransport.java:233)
at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.stop(TransportFilter.java:72)
at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.stop(TransportFilter.java:72)
at org.apache.activemq.transport.ResponseCorrelator.stop(ResponseCorrelator.java:132)
at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.doStop(TransportConnection.java:1194)
at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection$4.run(TransportConnection.java:1160)
... 3 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportDisposedIOException: peer (vm://localhost#5) stopped.
```

Unit test class looks like this:

```
@SpringBootTest                                                         
public class CucumberSpringIntegration {
@Rule
public EmbeddedActiveMQBroker broker = new EmbeddedActiveMQBroker();
  @Test                                                                            
  public void someUnitTest(){
   //some assertions
  }
```

configuration contains this:

```
java.naming.factory.initial = org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory    
java.naming.provider.url = vm://localhost?broker.persistent=false
```

The reference is from this link [activeMQ embedded Junit](https://activemq.apache.org/how-to-unit-test-jms-code)

Comment: Please post the full unit test source code.

Comment: @MattPavlovich updated test code in the original post

Answer (score 0):

You need to add pre-shutdown hook for your connection-factory. This happens when your broker is stopped before your connections get destroyed

```
@Rule
EmbeddedActiveMQBroker customizedBroker = new EmbeddedActiveMQBroker() {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        this.getBrokerService().setUseShutdownHook(true);
        this.getBrokerService().addPreShutdownHook(PROVIDE_SHUTDOWN_HOOK_HERE);
        // Perform additional configuration here...
    }
};
```

Comment: can you please let me know what logic to be added to the "PROVIDE_SHUTDOWN_HOOK_HERE" part